# How to get polyfill core node modules working on Webpack with Electron Forge

Tags: webpack, electron, polyfills, electron-forge

I'm trying to get the core node module polyfill working with my electron-forge project which uses Webpack 5.

I'm using an npm package which utilises a few of the core node modules, so Webpack is complaining since it can't compile unless I polyfill the core modules.
I've done what the docs say and added a fallback in the Webpack config, and installed literally every single polyfill, however the error just hasn't gone away.

This is what my webpack rules look like:

```
module.exports = [


// Add support for native node modules
  {
    test: /\.node$/,
    use: 'node-loader',
  },
  {
    test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
    use: [
      // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
      "style-loader",
      // Translates CSS into CommonJS
      "css-loader",
      // Compiles Sass to CSS
      "sass-loader",
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        presets: ['@babel/preset-react']
      }
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.(m?js|node)$/,
    parser: { amd: false },
    use: {
      loader: '@marshallofsound/webpack-asset-relocator-loader',
      options: {
        outputAssetBase: 'native_modules',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf|jpeg|svg|png)$/i,
    type: 'asset/resource',
  },
];
```

Anyone had any luck with this in the past?

Comment: Is this is resolved?